# Overlay two numpy arrays treating fourth plane as alpha level

Tags: python, image, numpy, alphablending, scikit-image

I have two numpy arrays of shape (256, 256, 4). I would like to treat the fourth 256 x 256 plane as an alpha level, and export an image where these arrays have been overlayed.

Code example:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

fg = np.ndarray((256, 256, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
one_plane = np.random.standard_normal((256, 256)) * 100 + 128
fg[:,:,0:3] = np.tile(one_plane, 3).reshape((256, 256, 3), order='F')
fg[:, :, 3] = np.zeros((256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
fg[0:128, 0:128, 3] = np.ones((128, 128), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
fg[128:256, 128:256, 3] = np.ones((128, 128), dtype=np.uint8) * 128

bg = np.ndarray((256, 256, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
bg[:,:,0:3] = np.random.standard_normal((256, 256, 3)) * 100 + 128
bg[:, :, 3] = np.ones((256, 256), dtype=np.uint8) * 255

io.imsave('test_fg.png', fg)
io.imsave('test_bg.png', bg)
```

This creates two images, fg:

[image: test_fg.png]

and bg:

[image: test_bg]:

I would like to be able to overlay the fg onto the bg. That is, the final image should have grey in the top left (because there the alpha of fg is 1), a blend of grey and colour noise in the bottom right, and pure colour noise in the other quandrants. I am looking for something like an add function that gives me a new np array.

Note that I don't think this is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127284/overlay-imshow-plots-in-matplotlib), which uses matplotlib.pyplot.plt to overlay the images and fiddles around with colour maps. I don't think I should need to fiddle with colour maps here, but maybe the answer is I do.

The reason I would like a new np.array returned by the operation is because I want to do this iteratively with many images, overlayed in order.

Comment: Reason to reopen: the _question_ is not duplicate; while the answer to the other question is general enough to answer this question also, this is not what the commonsense idea of "duplicate question" means. In this case, the other question/answer should have been pointed out in a comment instead of listing it as duplicate.

Comment: I do not think the question is a duplicate also. And it shows first in a google search for me (I am using numpy, not PIL)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Alpha blending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending) is usually done using the Porter & Duff equations:

[image]

where *src* and *dst* would correspond to your foreground and background images, and the *A* and *RGB* pixel values are assumed to be floating point, in the range *[0, 1]*.

For your specific example:

```
src_rgb = fg[..., :3].astype(np.float32) / 255.0
src_a = fg[..., 3].astype(np.float32) / 255.0
dst_rgb = bg[..., :3].astype(np.float32) / 255.0
dst_a = bg[..., 3].astype(np.float32) / 255.0

out_a = src_a + dst_a*(1.0-src_a)
out_rgb = (src_rgb*src_a[..., None]
           + dst_rgb*dst_a[..., None]*(1.0-src_a[..., None])) / out_a[..., None]

out = np.zeros_like(bg)
out[..., :3] = out_rgb * 255
out[..., 3] = out_a * 255
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Since @waldog is already using skimage, you can also use ```from skimage import img_as_float, img_as_ubyte``` to do the scaling and type conversions.

Comment: It is possible to get better visual results : the RGB values are square rooted (in order to keep accuracy for lower luminancy).

It is better to undo this before averaging : see  minute physics brilliant clip "Computer color is broken" about this here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw

Since this question is locked (marked as duplicate), here is a gist that does the correction : https://gist.github.com/pthom/5155d319a7957a38aeb2ac9e54cc0999